# VSCode debugging on running webpack-dev-server, skips breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, webpack, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server, vscode-debugger

I have debugger for chrome extension installed. I run my app using

```
webpack-dev-server -d --config webpack.dev.js --inline
```

I'm running a react app, all source codes are under /src folder. I have js, ts and tsx files. When I put a breakpoint on render function, editor properly breaks execution, but when I put a breakpoint to an onClick event of a button, it doesn't break, it just continues the execution of the code.

related part of my webpack config is as follows:

```
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    bundle: [
      '@babel/polyfill',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${host}:${devPort}`,
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash:16].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash:16].js',
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: devPort,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    hot: true,
    writeToDisk: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host,
  }
```

and my launch.json is as below:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///./src/*.js": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*.js",
    "webpack:///./src/*.tsx": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*.tsx",
    "webpack:///./src/*.ts": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*.ts",
    "webpack:///./node_modules/*": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/*"
  }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this to work by using `inline-source-map` in my config file:

```js
{
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    // ....
}
```

Now it works properly and breaks wherever I put the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with create-react-app. In `webpack.config.js` (after ejecting) I changed devtool: isEnvProduction? shouldUseSourceMap ? "inline-source-map" instead of "source-map" and now my breakpoints are constantly hitting!

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Another easy fix would be to add this configuration in `launch.json` and run your project before running the below debugger.

So what will happen in this config is it will open a new window in chrome with `url` you specified.

```
{
  "name": "Chrome",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  }
},
```

Hope this is helpful!!